# Android Studio 2.0 Preview: ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug' FAILED

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, android-json

I'm getting this error in Gradle in Android Studio:

```
:cart:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug FAILED
 Error:Execution failed for task  :cart:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.>
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gsonhtcfix.JsonSyntaxException`
```

I am not able to run/execute my project in Android Studio. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm getting the same ClassNotFoundException for some class I'm not using anymore.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Resolved :

Disable the Instant Run option in Android Studio 2.0 Preview

[image: See this screenshot]

Comment: Perfect Answer, Works for me,,

Comment: This does not resolve the issue, only disables a potentially incredible feature of Android Studio.

Comment: I don't see your suggestion of how to fix it, Michael Herbig. And it does resolve the issue of the app not launching, of course it doesn't fix the broken IDE feature but nobody said disabling something fixes it.

Comment: @MichaelHerbig Maybe it disables a great feature, but without disabling it I cannot debug! Now the question is, why we have to disable it and how to have a better solution

Comment: Thanks you! It's help me too

Comment: -1 Then Instant Run doesn't work anymore and I have to wait ages for an app restart for the tiniest changes to become active.

Comment: app worked and android is so buggy! upgrading is more awefull

Comment: I updated my Android Studio Gradle Plugin. And somehow I got that error. I tried many ways but did not get anyway work for my situation. finally i disabled the instant run setting. but What if I want to run instant run?

Comment: Perfect Answer, this trick resolved my issue.

Thanks my friend!

Answer (score 4):

Something you can try is deleting the build folder. That does not always work but fixes it sometimes.

```
rm -rf cart/build
```

If that does not work. Run that command then in Android Studio select invalidate caches and restart.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happen when the used `gradle` have problem with instant run.
So to solve this you have to either change `gradle` version or disable instant run.

Answer (score 0):

In my nexus 5 I have get only warrning, but another devices not complied, so I have disabled debug mode if i need it /

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles 'proguard-android.txt', 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```