# Dependency app does not run

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After I added the `android-3.2` dependency, it did not run in my smartphone and gave me this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>   Unexpected constructor structure.

[here is the image of adding dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8piu.png)

Whenever I don't add the dependency, the app runs in my smartphone. 
BTW, I don't use any emulator for testing my app, I just run directly in my smartphone.

please help me.

Comment: i also tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059352/android-studio-2-0-preview-apptransformclasseswithinstantrunfordebug-failed) formula but didn't get my perfect result.